# Android 6 requesting a permission

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

In android 6 I'm requesting a permission to use the storage. 
Now when the user denied my request I want to show him a dialog that explain why the permission is needed for the application in order to get his permission.

How can this be done?

Is there any built in dialog like the one that pop up's when you use the request permissions method?

Comment: refer [this](http://androidgig.com/requesting-runtime-permission/) , it will be usefull

Comment: You can show custom Dialog when user denied permission. It has callback method where you can check for permission is granted or not.

Comment: refer http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is good to show custom dialog before asking for permission, so that user can decide whether permission should be accept or decline.

you can use this

```
int hasReadPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

if (hasReadPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //show your custom dialog regarding why you need this permission
}
```

when user click on button of dialog, show them permission dialog by using

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
        50);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do following:

```
/**
 * Permission check for Marshmallow
 */
public void checkMallowPermissions() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {



        if(!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ||

                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          // Show your dialog
    }
}
```